# socket.io not connecting reactjs nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, apache, socket.io

In browser, it's saying connection failed. I want to connect `socket.io` with `reactjs` and `nodejs` backend I am using **Apache Ubuntu**

Server:

```js
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server, {
 cors: {
  origin: 'https://melodybot.me',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  credentials: true,
 },
 transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
 allowEIO3: true,
})
```

client:

```js
let connectionOptions = {
 'force new connection': true,
 reconnectionAttempts: 'Infinity',
 timeout: 10000,
 transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
}
const ws = new io(url, connectionOptions)
```

Comment: If you are currently testing on local server then the reason it's not working because you have specified origin value  "https://melodybot.me" which in case of local server not correct. You need to specify local url of your front end server.

Comment: i deployed its in producton and its not working in production